# react: memoize a function based on a parameter passed to said function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, lodash

I am trying to use [lodash's throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) inside a React component to make some other call. This is what I currently have:

```js
const requestDetails = useCallback(
    throttle((someId: number) => {
      dispatch(...);
    }, 30000)
, []);
```

I am trying to make it so that `requestDetails(someId)` only will run `dispatch` once every 30 seconds, at most, for each `someId` passed.

Therefore, I would need to return a different `throttle` function for each `someId`. However, the code above doesn't work: I think it is because there is only one `throttle` function created behind-the-scenes, and therefore `throttle` will only run once every 30 seconds for all calls, not per `someId`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use `useRef` to keep throttled function and call `useEffect` to listen to `someId` changes

```
const throttleRef = useRef(throttle((someId: number) => {
      dispatch(...);
    }, 30000))

useEffect(() => throttleRef.current(someId), [someId])
```

Comment: I don't think that would work because `someId` is passed into `requestDetails` as a parameter -- TS complains about not being able to find `someId`.

Comment: Hmm it's true, couls you try mt updated approach? That may help you to solve that problem @etnguyen03

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to generate a throttled function for each `someId` and store them using a ref. Whenever `useEffect` is called with a valid `someId` (not `undefined`), generate and store a function if none exists for this `someId`, and then call the function for that `someId`.

Define the type of the throttled functions:

```
import { throttle, DebouncedFunc } from "lodash";

type ThrottledCallId = DebouncedFunc<() => void>;
```

In you component create a ref with an object that would hold those functions:

```
const throttlesRef = useRef<Record<number, ThrottledCallId>>({});
```

In your `useEffect` as long as `someId` is not `undefined`:

1. If the `throttlesRef` object doesn't contain a throttled function, create the function for this `someId`.
2. Call the throttled  function for that `someId`.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const throttles = throttlesRef.current;

  if(someId !== undefined) {
    if(!throttles[someId]) {
      // create the throttled function for this someId
      throttles[someId] = throttle(() => dispatch(someId), 3000);
    }

    // call the throttled function for this someId
    throttles[someId]();
  }
}, [dispatch, someId])
```